# I can't hook using Frida

Tags: android, frida

I want to automatically enter username and password in a mobile application and press the login button. I couldn't make it anyway.

My code gives an error the first time it runs, I think the activity has not been created yet, when I switch to another activity in the mobile app and switch to loginactivity again, the code runs.

Frida Code :

```
"use strict";
if (Java.available) {
    Java.perform(function() {
    var main;
    Java.choose('com.xxx.xxxxxx.activities.LoginActivity', {
            onMatch: function(instance) {
                main = instance;
            },
            onComplete: function() {}
        });


    var button = Java.use('android.widget.TextView');
    var checkid = main.findViewById(2131362200);
    var check = Java.cast(checkid, button);
    var string = Java.use('java.lang.String');
    check.setText(string.$new("xxxxxx@gmail.com"));

    var button2 = Java.use('android.widget.TextView');
    var checkid2 = main.findViewById(2131362201);
    var check2 = Java.cast(checkid2, button2);
    var string2 = Java.use('java.lang.String');
    check2.setText(string2.$new("1234543546"));

    console.warn('Done');
  });
} else {
 console.log("Java not available in this process");
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.xxx.xxxxx.activities;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.xxx.xxxxx.NativeApi;
import com.xxx.xxxxx.Singleton.DeviceSuspendManager.DeviceSuspendManager;
import org.json.JSONException;
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;
private Button mBtnLogin;
private TextInputEditText mInputEmail;
private TextInputEditText mInputPassword;
private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private View.OnClickListener mLoginClick = new 1(this);
private View.OnClickListener mSignupClick = new 2(this);
private View.OnClickListener mForgotPasswordClick = new 3(this);
private int errorcounter = 0;

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
}

static /* synthetic */ int access$412(LoginActivity loginActivity, int i) {
    int i2 = loginActivity.errorcounter + i;
    loginActivity.errorcounter = i2;
    return i2;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(2131558438);
    this.mInputEmail = findViewById(2131362200);
    this.mInputPassword = findViewById(2131362201);
    if (bundle != null) {
        String string = bundle.getString("username");
        String string2 = bundle.getString("password");
        this.mInputEmail.setText(string);
        this.mInputPassword.setText(string2);
    }
    this.mBtnLogin = (Button) findViewById(2131361957);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(2131362241);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(2131362235);
    Button button = this.mBtnLogin;
    if (button != null) {
        button.setOnClickListener(this.mLoginClick);
    }
    if (textView != null) {
        textView.setOnClickListener(this.mSignupClick);
    }
    if (textView2 != null) {
        textView2.setOnClickListener(this.mForgotPasswordClick);
    }
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    String trim = this.mInputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String obj = this.mInputPassword.getText().toString();
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    bundle.putString("username", trim);
    bundle.putString("password", obj);
}

public void onActivityResult(int i, int i2, Intent intent) {
    if (i == 0 && i2 == -1) {
        onLoginSuccess();
    }
}

public void showError(String str) {
    View findViewById = findViewById(2131362064);
    if (findViewById != null) {
        findViewById.setVisibility(0);
        ((TextView) findViewById.findViewById(2131362065)).setText(str);
    }
}

private boolean validate() {
    Boolean bool = true;
    String trim = this.mInputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String obj = this.mInputPassword.getText().toString();
    if (trim.isEmpty() || !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(trim).matches()) {
        showError(getString(2131886796));
        bool = false;
    } else {
        this.mInputEmail.setError((CharSequence) null);
    }
    if (obj.isEmpty()) {
        showError(getString(2131886797));
        bool = false;
    } else {
        this.mInputPassword.setError((CharSequence) null);
    }
    return bool.booleanValue();
}

public void doLogin() {
    if (validate()) {
        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService("input_method")).hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus() == null ? null : getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 2);
        String trim = this.mInputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String obj = this.mInputPassword.getText().toString();
        String str = this.TAG;
        Log.d(str, "Logging in " + trim + " (" + obj + ")");
        try {
            DeviceSuspendManager.getInstance().setSavedPassword(obj);
            DeviceSuspendManager.getInstance().setSavedUsername(trim);
            Log.d(this.TAG, NativeApi.attach(trim, obj, "", new LoginCallback(this, this)).toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            showError(getString(2131886369));
            Log.e(this.TAG, "Attaching account failure");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void onLoginSuccess() {
    setResult(10);
    finish();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

}

I think the main causes of the problem are:

The use of google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText widget instead of android.widget.TextView.

Secondly, the code can run before loginActivity occurs.

Waiting for your solutions, thank you.

Comment: Next time please include the full error message when posting code that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

One major problem of your code is located in the code block at the beginning:

```
    var main;
    Java.choose('com.xxx.xxxxxx.activities.LoginActivity', {
            onMatch: function(instance) {
                main = instance;
            },
            onComplete: function() {}
        });


    var button = Java.use('android.widget.TextView');
    var checkid = main.findViewById(2131362200);
```

`Java.choose` works asynchronous, that means the code execution continues even if `Java.choose` is not yet completed. This is common for JavaScript functions.

Therefore if you reach the line `var checkid = main.findViewById(2131362200);` the variable `main` may not be set yet, as `Java.choose` has not completed.

If you want to use variables in `onMatch` of `Java.choose` you have to put the code in `onComplete`:

```
"use strict";
if (Java.available) {
    Java.perform(function() {
    var main;
    Java.choose('com.xxx.xxxxxx.activities.LoginActivity', {
            onMatch: function(instance) {
                main = instance;
            },
            onComplete: function() {
                var button = Java.use('android.widget.TextView');
                var checkid = main.findViewById(2131362200);
                var check = Java.cast(checkid, button);
                var string = Java.use('java.lang.String');
                check.setText(string.$new("xxxxxx@gmail.com"));

                var button2 = Java.use('android.widget.TextView');
                var checkid2 = main.findViewById(2131362201);
                var check2 = Java.cast(checkid2, button2);
                var string2 = Java.use('java.lang.String');
                check2.setText(string2.$new("1234543546"));

                console.warn('Done');
            }
        });


  });
} else {
 console.log("Java not available in this process");
}
```